# Generate possible values for dice rolls

Tags: java

I need a program in java that is capable to generate all possible combination of a dice roll. The number of dice as well as faces in dice may vary.
for example.
A combination of 3 six faced dice may be as follows.
111
112
113
114
115
116
121
122
123
124
125
126... and so on.... until 666.
any help???
some kind of

```
public Map generatePossibleNumbers(int face, int numberOfDice){
   // generate numbers and return map
   Map generatedMap=new HashMap();
   return generatedMap;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Sorry bro i was asking advice.. mr zero... you may not answer if you dont wish...

Comment: I suggest you try to generate more of the sequence by hand. Start to look for patterns. Then describe **in words** the steps you need to take to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a `Collection` instead of a `Map` since you are not going to need to store `Key-Value` pairs.

This is what I came up with:

```
public static void diceRoll(int dice, int numberOfDice) {
    Deque<Integer> list = new ArrayDeque<>(dice);
    diceRoll(dice, numberOfDice, list); // initially we have chosen nothing
}

// Private recursive helper method to implement diceRoll method.
// Adds a 'list' parameter of a list representing
private static void diceRoll(int dice, int numberOfDice, Deque<Integer> list) {
    if (dice == 0) {
        // Base Case: nothing left to roll. Print all of the outcomes.
        System.out.println(list);
    } else {
        // Recursive case: dice >= 1.
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDice; i++) {
            list.addLast(i); // choose
            diceRoll(dice - 1, numberOfDice, list); // explore
            list.removeLast(); // un-choose
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. But please try to understand the code, not just copy it. ;)

Comment: Yes i fugured, you recursively called the method... that was real helpful :)